# writing a simple function in assembly x86-64

Tags: assembly, x86-64, memory-address

I am trying to write the first function for a lab written in x86-64 assembly language that is called multInts. It will multiply the first element of intArray1 with the first element of intArray2 and then the second, etc. The function prototype is `void multInts(int size, int *array1, int *array2);`
Here is the .data section for the lab:

```
.data
sizeIntArrays:
    .long 5
sizeShortArrays:
    .word 4
intArray1:
    .long 10
    .long 25
    .long 33
    .long 48
    .long 52
intArray2:
    .long 20
    .long -37
    .long 42
    .long -61
    .long -10
```

Here is what I've written so far:

```
##### MAIN FUNCTION
.text
.globl main
.type main,@function

main:
pushq %rbp
movq %rsp, %rbp

#pass parameters and call other functions
movl sizeIntArrays, %edi    #move size to registers for 1st parameter
leaq intArray1, %rsi        #load effective address of intArray1 to register rsi
leaq intArray2, %rdx        #load effective address of intArray2 to register rdx
movq $intArray1, %r10
movq $intArray2, %r11
call multInts           #call multInts function


movq $0, %rax           #return 0 to caller

movq %rbp, %rsp
popq %rbp
ret
.size main,.-main


##### MULTINTS
.globl multInts
.type multInts,@function

multInts:
pushq %rbp
movq %rsp, %rbp

#add code here for what the functions should do
movq $0, %r8            #initialize index for array access in caller save reg
movq $0, %rcx           #initialize 8 byte caller save result reg

loop0:
cmpl %r8d, %edi         #compare index to size
je exit0            #exit if equal
imulq (%r10, %r11), %rcx    #multiply elements of both array and store in result  reg
incq %r8            #increment index
jmp loop0

exit0:
movq $.LC0, %rdi
movq %rcx, %rsi
movq $0, %rax

call printf

movq %rbp, %rsp
popq %rbp
ret
.size multInts,.-multInts
```

So, what I'm having trouble figuring out is how to make a pointer to intArray1 as required by the function prototype and then how to call it correctly in the multInts function? I tried using leaq to store the address of intArray1 & 2 to registers, but then I don't know how to access the values. Also, I'm not entirely certain I'm using the imulq function properly to multiply the two values together. I keep receiving a segmentation fault as soon as the code attempts to execute multInts. Let me know if more information is needed, and thank you.

Comment: `movq $.LC0, %rdi`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.long` is the same as `.int`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Long.html) and its size is 4 bytes. Therefore, you can't process it directly with [`imulq`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/IMUL.html) (apart from the fact that the syntax is wrong). You can load the signed value into a x64-register with [`movsx`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVSX:MOVSXD.html) (Intel syntax) resp [`movslq`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMnemonics.html) (AT&T syntax).

I suppose that `RCX` should contain the sum of the multiplications.

Change

```
imulq (%r10, %r11), %rcx    #multiply elements of both array and store in result  reg
```

to

```
movslq (%rsi,%r8,4),%rax    # Load a long into RAX
movslq (%rdx,%r8,4),%r11    # Load a long into R11
imulq %r11, %rax            # RAX *= R11
addq %rax, %rcx             # RCX += RAX
```

and delete

```
movq $intArray1, %r10
movq $intArray2, %r11
```

You don't need it.